# RubyMine - Running RSpec/ jruby Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, out-of-memory, jruby, rubymine

I've recently been blessed with RubyMine 8.0.3 at work and despite the IDE being quite easy to use, I am having troubles with running my RSpec tests through the built in RSpec console. The problem is that my specs fail during the initial set-up with the error "Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded".

I am aware that this is the java garbage collector running out of memory- probably caused by some inefficient code somewhere that pre-dates my involvement in the project. However, I have no problem running the rspec tests through the bash console, outside of RubyMine, with the command rspec "path/to/test_spec.rb".

The set-up process is actually a bit quicker here, but I hate trolling through all the poorly indented error lines in the console when my tests do actually execute, hence my preference of using RubyMines nice way of inspecting failures/ successful tests (why pay for the subscription if you're not gonna use it, right?)

By the looks of things, RubyMine calls some sort of jruby command before the RSpec- so is there a way to configure RubyMine to not invoke JRuby when running rspec tests? Or at least a way to configure the jruby GC in RubyMine, so that I don't run into these memory issues?

Thanks,

Comment: https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store is what I used to solve this:

Answer (score 1):

**[SOLVED]** So after a bit of digging around in the IDE's various options, I found an "edit configurations" option from the run/debug environment drop down. Here you can set environment variables for JRuby. If you click on the RSpec option, this will extend to show all of your RSpec tests. Clicking on them will show the configurations for that test, which includes an option called "Environment Variables". If you stick `-J-Xmx2048m` in there, this will allocate 2048mb's to the JRuby memory heap.

As expected, this solves the issue, as RubyMine seems to be restricting the amount of memory the JRuby runtime has available by default.

Obviously, you can change the memory value to whatever your machine is capable of, but this solves the issue.